# How Do I Call a Method After a File Has Finished Downloading In Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, download

I am writing a program for the Oculus Go that can download a video file to be used later.

I have been using the following IEnumerator to do this:

```
IEnumerator DownloadFile()
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading file");
    UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+fileID);
    Debug.Log("File found");
    DownloadHandlerBuffer dH = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.downloadHandler = dH;
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.LogError(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        rawVideoData = www.downloadHandler.data;
        FinishDownload();
    }
}
```

and then FinishDownload just writes rawVideoData (which is a byte array) into a file and so on.

Problem is, the program seems to just skip downloading the file and jump straight to everything else, which ends up giving me an error when I try to access the video later.

What am I doing wrong here? I've been stumped on this issue for weeks.

Also, is there an easy way to check the progress of the download while during runtime? That may make things a bit easier on me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're trying to call `FinishDownload()` before the operation finished executing. Try to follow this flow:

```
        var www = new UnityWebRequest("url");
        // Implement web request functionality here 
        www.SendWebRequest().completed += operation =>
        {
            // code here will execute when your web request operation will be completed 
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But where would I put my yield return statement? I tried placing the www.SendWebRequest().completed += operation block after it, and it told be that it can't begin sending SendWebRequest a second time.